# Implementing which function in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to implement Unix's `which` function, but keep getting syntax errors, on what I (think) is legal? This is my implementation:

```
IFS=":"
x=false

for i in $*
do
    for j in $PATH
    do
        if [ -x "${j}/$i" ];then
            echo $j/$i
            x=true
            break 
        fi
    done
    if [ $x == false ]; then
        echo my_which $i not found in --$PATH--

    fi
    x=false

done
```

I keep getting the following error

```
$ bash which.sh
: command not found:
'which.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'which.sh: line 5: `do
```

Comment: ...also, `==` isn't the POSIX string comparison operator -- it's `=`; some implementations may accept `==`, but they aren't required to do so by the standard. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: ...and always quote your expansions. `echo "my_which $i not found in --$PATH--"`

Comment: copy-paste the code you've posted and test it again.

Comment: Good point, Karoly -- good chance this has DOS newlines, which would explain the `do`s not being valid, since that would make them `do$'\r'`, no longer matching the keyword.

Comment: actually, not just a "good chance", but **certain**, given the error message having closing quotes at the very beginning.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath just tried that, still getting the same error :-( I updated with other suggestions from this post, still receiving the same error.

Comment: @unicornication, tried that how? If you saved it with the same editor that created your file with DOS newlines in the first place, it's not going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has DOS newlines. Use `dos2unix` to convert it, or open it in an editor that can do the conversion for you (in vim, you would run `:set fileformat=unix` and then save with `:w`).

```
$ bash which.sh
: command not found:
'which.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'which.sh: line 5: `do
```

See the `'`s at the beginning of those lines? Those are supposed to be at the *end* of the line.

What's happening, however, is that your `do`s have a hidden `$'\r'` character after them, which sends the cursor back to the beginning of the line. Thus, instead of seeing `do` as a valid token, or correctly printing

```
# this is the error you would get if your "do" were really a "do", but it were still
# ...somehow bad syntax.
syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

...we get...

```
# this is the error you get when your "do" is really a $'do\r'
'yntax error near unexpected token `do
```

...because a carriage return is sitting between the `do` and the `'`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using Vim and saving worked. :-)